# GHCup installed with HLS (latest) doesn't work with VS Code HLS Extension for Intellisense

Tags: haskell, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, haskell-language-server, ghcup

**Context:** 
I run a Windows machine, and I've installed the Haskell Toolchain using GHCup. Initially, I selected "Y" to all the options mentioned during setup. Stack, Cabal, ghc (8.10.7 - recommended) worked and were/are on path (installation reference link attached at the end).

**Sample Project Structure ("stack new project"):** 
[image]

**Problem:** 
The Haskell Language Server Extension does not give me Intellisense. It did, for a brief moment after my first install, but never again.

**Things I've tried that did not work:**

1. *Letting VS Code manage HLS via GHCup, to upgrade* whenever, but to no avail. 
   [image]
2. Tried reinstalling everything, but that hasn't worked either.
3. Using the latest/same version of ghc that came with ghcup stack.
   (stack ghc -- -version = 9.0.2, ghc --version = 9.0.2)

Note: I did do the following commands too, with varying combinations (but in some logically dependent order)

- ghcup install ghc 9.0.2 (and latest)
- ghcup unset ghc 8.10.7
- ghcup set ghc 9.0.2 (and latest)
- ghcup rm ghc 8.10.7

All I end up getting is this cryptic message (shown below. "testing-p" is the project name).

[image]

**Installation Reference:** 
https://betterprogramming.pub/haskell-vs-code-setup-in-2021-6267cc991551

Comment: Okay so standalone Haskell files work with the Haskell HLS extension. However, cabal or stack based builds don't work

Comment: I needed to compile HLS for my specific GHC version using `ghcup compile hls -v <hlsv> --ghc <ghcv>`

Comment: I did try that command, however ghcup said that it had trouble resolving dependencies, any idea as to how I should proceed? Also, assuming that this compilation does work (in the future for me), do I have to then set the HLS path inside VS Code for the haskell extension?